# Transit Visa required for London while going to USA?

Tags: visas, uk, transit, london, lhr

I hold a valid Indian passport and I would be travelling to the USA (from India) with a valid US Visa the coming weekend. I have a long layover of 10 hours at the LHR terminal 5. I would like to roam around London a bit for few hours using the underground tube. My question is if I need a transit visa for going out of the airport and getting back again. Needless to say I would be passing through the customs and immigration of UK border control.

Please respond ASAP.

Avik,
India.

Comment: This website may help https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa

Comment: Thanks @Gagravarr , I have already seen that post before posting this question. But I couldn't find an exact scenario/answer where I would like to roam around London for couple of hours WITHOUT the transit visa. I mean is that possible at all? I am travelling from India to the USA with a valid US Visa. I have 10 hours layover at LHR 5 (both inbound and outbound are BA flights arriving/departing Terminal 5). Kindly respond, if you have an answer!